# Merge two eloquent collections with identical keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

Lets say I have a collection like

```
{
    "object1": [
        {
            "name" xxx,
            "size" 999
        }
    ],
    "object2": [
        {
            "name": yyy,
            "size": 888,
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have another collection like

```
{
    "object2": [
        {
            "name" aaa,
            "size" 111
        }
    ],
    "object3": [
        {
            "name": bbb,
            "size": 222,
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to get a collection like

```
{
    "object1": [
        {
            "name" xxx,
            "size" 999
        }
    ],
    "object2": [
        {
            "name": yyy,
            "size": 888,
        },
        {
            "name" aaa,
            "size" 111
        }
    ],
    "object3": [
        {
            "name": bbb,
            "size": 222,
        }
    ]
}
```

[mergeRecursively](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-mergerecursive) works but it encapsulates the extra results in an "items" array which looks like this

```
{
    "object1": [
        {
            "name" xxx,
            "size" 999
        }
    ],
    "object2": {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": yyy,
                "size": 888,
            },
            {
                "name" aaa,
                "size" 111
            }
        ]
    ],
    "object3": [
        {
            "name": bbb,
            "size": 222,
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Collection::each()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-each) to iterate through each item of one collection and build a replacement collection.

```php
$results = new Collection;
$collection1->each(function($item, $key) use ($collection2, $results) {
    $push = $collection2->has($key) ? $item->mergeRecursive($collection2->get($key)) : $item;
    $results[$key] = $push;
});
dump($results);
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Can you explain the code snippet you provided?

Comment: Didn't realize that `map()` doesn't preserve keys, so try this one. If you need further assistance, update your question with some code that can be copied for testing. It's more difficult to help without sample data.

Comment: Getting an error `Property [key] does not exist on this collection instance`. Collection 1 and Collection 2 have more than 1 item. mergeRecursively works great but if there is a way to eliminate that extra array where the merged data is encapsulated.

Comment: Fixed a typo, should be `$collection2->get($key)`. As I said, it's harder to do without any sample data.

Comment: Thanks @miken32. Your answer helped. However, I edited it slightly to the structure that was exactly needed.